# Conditional compiling in source code

Tags: c, visual-c++

I need to use `strncpy_s` in my code. The code needs to be compiled using msvc71 as well as msvc90 compilers. It turns out that `strncpy_s` is not supported in msvc71. I have implemented my own version of `strncpy_s`

So I want to compile this implementation of `strncpy_s` only when the compiler is msvc71. How can I do this?

Comment: There is a macro to identify the compiler

Comment: [`_MSC_VER` et al](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)

Comment: If you have your own version, just use it all the time.

Comment: You can still use `strncpy` in msvc90. This is cleaner then using a conditional compilation.

Comment: @PeteBecker What? that's not a good idea.

Comment: @iharob - why not? If the user's version works correctly it works correctly.

Comment: Because the default implementation will necessarily be more efficient, unless the user implements it like the Microsoft C Runtime does.

Comment: @FUZxxl - **dont't** use `strncpy` until you've read its documentation carefully and understood it. It is **not** a drop-in "safe" replacement for `strcpy`.

Comment: @iharob - um, if the user's version isn't a bottleneck for the old compiler, there's no reason to assume it will be a bottleneck for the new compiler. Swapping implementations around can, however, be a bottleneck for development. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @PeteBecker What can I say, "*If it ain't broke, don't fix it*" is the voice of experience so I agree.

Comment: @FUZxxl: `strncpy` and `strncpy_s` have different semantics.  Suggesting `strncpy` is a bad idea.  Its behavior is obscure and counterintuitive. Even if you know exactly what it does, most programmers reading your code will not and will think it is a *cool* replacement for `strcpy`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Of course. If available, I recommend the use of `strlcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

Using conditional compilation is not a very good solution to your problem: if you later compile with another compiler or on a different platform, you will need to add more and more special tests to handle these environments that may or may not support `strncpy_s`.  There is a standard way to request for these extended functions and to check whether they are available, but I strongly recommend you define your replacement function at all times, name it something else and use it unconditionally.

As you may be aware, `strncpy` and `strncpy_s` are not interchangeable, they have different semantics, beyond the extra argument for the size of the destination.  `strncpy` definitely should not be used, because it is error prone: even if you master its peculiar side effects, other programmers later reading or modifying your code will not. `strncpy_s` has its own quirks: the behavior on constraint violation may not be what you expect.